# ziped ocmod.xml not working in opencart 3.0

Tags: php, xml, opencart, ocmod

I have created an ocmode.xml and uploaded the archived file through opencert 3.0 extension->installer. I am getting success message and i have refresh the cache but it's not working.

Here is the code

```
<modification>
    <name>TESTER</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <link>http://www.example.com</link>
    <author>Sainul</author>
    <code>price_slider_filter</code>

    <file path="catalog/controller/account/login.php">
        <operation> 
            <search ><![CDATA[$this->load->model('account/customer');]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[ echo 'TEST'; ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Answer (score 0):

1)change your `xxx.xml` file name to `install.xml`

2)archive the file as `xxx.ocmod.zip`.

3)go to `extension->installer` ,and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is creating ocmod.zip file

I am explaining by example

Suppose we have an extension that have following files as
**upload
install.xml**

then we need to zip both files as **extension_name.ocmod.zip**
But if we extract this zip file then files should not be extracted in extension_name directory
The **.ocmod.zip** file should be extracted with **extension_name** directory

as
**upload
install.xml**

Hope it will solve your issue
The code is written in admin/controller/marketplace/install.php in line number 104